# How to syncronize one object from two sources

Tags: c#, synchronization

I want to synchronize one variable (`Node.Value`) to two separate sources. Both sources can read or write to their `internalValue` variable. How do I keep track of the newest value and update appropriately? I need to run this process multiple times a second. The sources are not necessarily databases.

I was thinking about temporarily saving the `Node.Value` on `ServiceB` and before I update the new value  to `SourceB` I would check if they are still the same (`Service.B.TempNode.Value` and `SourceB.InternalValue`). If **not** then there is a change to `SourceB` so I could update from B to A.
Or work with `IChangeTracking`, but then I cant figure out which `Service` should read or write first...

Nonetheless this doesn't seem to be a good implementation at all. I just need to get an idea of the concept. Currently I cant wrap my head around it.

**Rough visualization:**
[image: graph]

**Example:**

```
public class ServiceManager
{
    public Node Node {get; set;}
    public void Update()
    {
        // this only synchronizes A to B
        while(true)
        {
            ServiceA.ReadFromExternal();
            ServiceB.WriteToExternal();
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional infos**
Sorry if I haven’t provided much details, wanted to keep it as simple as possible. In reality there are multiple services. The main goal is to synchronize all sources to the newest value while providing the best performance. The source is only a variable and I am only able to poll it manually in my ServiceManager. It can’t hold any additional information like time stamps etc. If I handle Node as a object to be passed around I’m not sure how to determine which value is the newest. Wether I should write the current Node.Value to the source or vise versa.

Comment: Where possible, you avoid it. Which source is the source of truth? Are both services on the same machine? In the same process? There are a number of different approaches, each with their own trade offs and limitations. We’ll need some more info to advise you which route to take.

Comment: @Telastyn All services run on the same machine. The sources can be outside or inside the machine. I added some additional info above.

Comment: Are ServiceA, ServiceB, and ServiceManager independently running processes (programs) or are they classes within a single process?

Comment: Currently my idea is to run them in one app on one task. Maybe in the future I’ll have each service in a separate task if this would increase performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the underlying problem is that Node is a shared value with multiple copies/access points.

Can you externalize Node and make it an object to be passed around so that only the service with a reference to the object can write to the object?

Does it make more sense to make Node a shared resource to be protected by a synchronization primitive?

Apologies if I’m vague on details. I think my response is suitable in a comment but there’s a stupid 50 reputation requirement for posting comments.

Edit 1:

> The main goal is to synchronize all sources to the newest value while
> providing the best performance. The source is only a variable and I am
> only able to poll it manually in my ServiceManager. It can’t hold any
> additional information like time stamps etc. If I handle Node as a
> object to be passed around I’m not sure how to determine which value
> is the newest.

Have you considered using [MSDN:Events](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/) in lieu of polling?

Let's give these objects names so we're clear about what we're working with (your diagram isn't a class diagram I'm use to seeing). If I understand correctly, there are essentially four types of classes: Node, ServiceA, ServiceB, ServiceManager (with the understanding that you might have other Services). ServiceA and ServiceB each have a Node member. I'm assuming ServiceManager also has a Node member (or perhaps it accesses another Service's Node member; It's unclear what the relationship between ServiceManager and Node is. That single arrow pointing from ServiceManager to Node is unhelpful).

By "synchronized", I mean if **any** object modifies its Node member, other objects in synchronization will see the same change to their own Node member.

Now, terminology aside, are there synchronization restrictions?
e.g., ServiceManager can't write to its Node and only receives updates from other Service.Nodes. e.g., If ServiceA modifies its Node, only ServiceManager.Node is synchronized. ServiceB.Node remains unchanged/outdated (ServiceA.Node is synchronized with ServiceManager.Node, ServiceB.Node is sychronized with ServiceManager.Node but ServiceA.Node is *not* synchronized with ServiceB.Node).

.. or are the Nodes from ServiceA, ServiceB, and ServiceManager synchronized? If so, then Node is a shared resource. Use a [synchronization primitive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) to ensure exclusive access to the Node whenever a Service or ServiceManager wants to update the value.

Comment: Upvoted, now you have 50 reps.

Comment: Having the Node as a shared variable made the most sense to me but I guess I’ll have it passed around like you mentioned. Maybe I could have each service hold it’s own temporary node so I could see if the old one changed to the new source value. If so I can update the shared one.

Comment: ServiceA, ServiceB and ServiceManager access the same variable (Node) by reference. So if either ServiceA or B change the Node.Value it should update all Services linked to that Node. The main issue for me is how to figure out which source to read or write first implying I have a loop as mentioned in my question. Switching to events might help me in with this.

Comment: I’ll assign every service it’s own task and only update their node if the value actually changes. Then fire a event to update all subscribed Services from that Node. Do u think this will bottleneck when I have multiples nodes firing multiple events couple times a second?

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on your consistency requirements, which since you didn't mention at all, you're in for some research. Is it important that they always agree on what the value is at any given time, or is it okay if they simply see the changes in the same order? Do they need to see every individual value, or is it okay to just get occasional updates? Do you need to do atomic read-modify-write cycles? Is it more important to never see a duplicate message, or more important to never miss a message? Is speed more important or making sure every value is saved to disk before being used?

Most programmers use a service like ZooKeeper, Redis, Kafka, or a database for replication, depending on the answers to the above questions. These might seem like overkill, but they have already solved problems you haven't even started thinking about yet. What if one of your services goes down or reboots? What if some packets get lost or arrive out of order? What if your services disagree on what the value should be? What if you need to restore your services to the state they were in yesterday?

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I added some additional infos. 
For now it’s not important if a service goes down or reboots.